# How do I do the Update raw query in Doctrine?

Tags: php, sql, symfony1, doctrine

I need to update extra field in associative table with a raw query how do I do it. Nothing is working !!!!!

Comment: Please edit this post and add the code which is causing problems for you, along with any errors that are being issued, etc.  Without that it's not likely you'll get much in the way of responses.

Comment: I figured out! the andwer below works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me with Doctrine 1.2 when doing an UPDATE:

```
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()
  ->getCurrentConnection()
  ->execute("UPDATE table t SET t.field = 1 WHERE t.id = 2");
```